# Play videos one after another in VideoView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-videoview

In my app, I have a list of videos and i am not sure how to play them one after another.

Here is the code to play a single video:

```
 var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString () + "/" + i + ".mp4");        
 vi.SetVideoURI (uri);
 vi.Start (); 

 where vi is a VideoView and i = 1,2,3...n
```

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Search for Android MediaControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working,

```
            VideoView vi = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.video2);

            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString () + "/" + 1 + ".mp4");        
            vi.SetVideoURI (uri);
            vi.Start (); 
            int i = 2;
            vi.Completion += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                if(i<= NoOfFiles)
                {
                    var uri2 = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString () + "/" + i + ".mp4");        
                    vi.SetVideoURI (uri2);
                    vi.Start (); 
                    i++;
                }
            };
```

Where NoOfFiles = total number of videos;

Answer (score 0):

You can use getBufferPercentage(), getDuration (),getCurrentPosition () these three methods related to videoview.It solves your problems.

Answer (score 0):

use exoPlayer.
this library help you to concatenate multi video together